# D3.js how to transition in opposite direction with basic SVG elements

Tags: animation, d3.js, css-transitions, transition

Currently the D3 transition of this bar starts from left to right, I believe it's the default.

How can I make a transition start from right to left instead?
Here's my transition:
https://jsfiddle.net/kxg9x4gq/39/

```
var svg = d3.select("#foo")

var bar = svg.append("g")
             .attr("transform", "translate(20,20)")

bar.append("rect")
   .attr("height", 15)
   .transition().duration(700)
   .attr("width", 400)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can get the bar to transition from right to left by setting its `x` attribute before and after the transition.

```js
var svg = d3.select("#foo")

var bar = svg.append("g")
             .attr("transform", "translate(20,20)")

bar.append("rect")
   .attr("height", 15)
   .attr("x", 400)
   .transition().duration(700)
   .attr("width", 400)
   .attr("x", 0)
```

```css
rect {
  fill: #CCC;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.4.11/d3.min.js"></script>
<svg id="foo" height="200" width="400"></svg>
```

**Note:** I changed the width of the `svg` element to get this to work properly on the Stack Snippet above. It does seem to work on [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/j3vuoafd/) with your original value.